# Как поменять значение (true/false) переменной при клике?

Tags: reactjs

const [isActive, setisActive] = React.useState(false);

<button onClick={() => setisActive((isActive = true))} className={isActive ? 'likeBtn_active' : 'likeBtn'}>

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onClick={() => setisActive((prevActive) => !prevActive)} className={isActive ? 'likeBtn_active' : 'likeBtn'}>
```

Если я правильно понял